# Android Calculator App - Some Questions

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, calculator

I'm new to android application development. I'm trying to create a calculator application, and I got 2 questions to ask.

**1.**
How can I create a new row in LinearLayout?
It's currently looking like this:

[textview][textview][button]

And I want it to look like this:

[textview][textview]

[button]

This is my xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/number1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/number2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_calculate" />
```

**2.** How can I process the sum of "number1" and "number2" Textviews and display it on the Main Activity (where the TextViews are)?

Answer (score 0):

Linear layout can be horizontal or vertical, if you need rows and columns you need to work with relative layout or just add more then one linear layout such as..

```
TextView txtvar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewIdFromXml);
txtvar.setText("blah");
```

this how you connect to textview element whit id textViewIdFromXml and set blah for text

Comment: How can I change my code to RelativeLayout so I can work with multiple rows? I tried with no success.

Comment: In xml -root layout<LinearLayout> <RelativeLayout><textView></RelativeLayout></LinearLayout>

Comment: or <LinearLayout vertical> <LinearLayout horizontal> </LinearLayout> </LinearLayout> and you can combitate it whatever you want

Comment: Alright thanks, do you have any idea about the 2nd question? :)

Comment: Thanks. Is there just text output to the screen and not to an input box (TextView)?

Comment: ^ My bad, I got confused between TextView and EditText, I'm now trying it.

Comment: I`m not sure what are you asking but for calculator you need textview to display integers and buttons for set integers.

Comment: Yeah but I'm trying to make a very very simple one. How can I turn the number the user inputs in EditText1 and EditText2 into integers?

Comment: http://cloud101.eu/blog/2012/03/10/android-introduction-to-a-simple-calculator/ this example is what you need but it was not to simple. If you try it you will learn some basic stuff, but i suggest you to start whit http://developer.android.com/index.html you will need 2-3 days to read all the important info you need and then it will be very easy to start programming if you have some OOP skills in java c or other languages. Accept my answer pleas because i will not answer to you again

Answer (score 0):

1. Nested linear layouts.

For example (pseudo xml):

```
<Linear Layout : Vertical>
   <Linear Layout : Horizontal>
       <TextView />
       <TextView />
   </Linear Layout>
   <Button />
</Linear Layout>
```

Edit: I tried the following in Eclipse and for me it does what I think you ask (though it doesn't look fancy):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I did as you told me: [VERTICAL] [HORIZONTAL] [textview] [textview] [/HORIZONTAL] [button] [/VERTICAL] but the button doesn't appear, only the TextViews appear.

Comment: I got curious and tried it in Eclipse. I edited with some real xml.

Comment: Yeah I just had a problem with the first LinearLayout and it covered the button, now it works just fine, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**1st Ans:** create a Vertical Linear Layout & use a Horinzental one nested in the Vertical one. But I prefer relative layout.

**2ns Ans:** use `onClickListener()` for the buttons. & under every `onClickListener()` change the text of Number display textbox using `setText()`. but on = button's `onClickListener()` use the value of Number display textbox using `getText()` and use it for + - or in * /

Comment: Thanks, I used "android:onClick" I finally got everything to work thank you everyone :)